# Options on the order page opencart 2.3

Tags: opencart, cart, opencart2.x, opencart2.3

I'm trying to make editing options on the checkout page.
Added function by analogy with quantity

```
    public function update_two($cart_id, $option = array()) {
    $this->db->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "cart SET option =  '" . $this->db->escape(json_encode($option)) . "'  WHERE cart_id = '" . (int)$cart_id . "' AND customer_id = '" . (int)$this->customer->getId() . "' AND session_id = '" . $this->db->escape($this->session->getId()) . "'");
}
```

Then there is an error

```
 Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'option = '{\"232\":[\"23\"],\"228\":[\"19\"]}' WHERE cart_id = '198' AND custo' at line 1<br />Error No: 1064<br />
```

UPDATE: line ~ 283

```
    public function updatetwo($cart_id, $option = array()) {
    $this->db->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "cart SET `option` = '" . $this->db->escape(serialize(json_encode($option))) . "' WHERE cart_id = '" . (int)$cart_id . "' AND customer_id = '" . (int)$this->customer->getId() . "' AND session_id = '" . $this->db->escape($this->session->getId()) . "'");
}
```

Line ~ 50 : `$options_alt = unserialize($cart['option']);
                foreach (json_decode($options_alt) as $product_option_id => $value) {`
**If anyone needs - everything works**

Comment: the issue seems to be with the options `array`. try only `json_encode($option)` instead of `$this->db->escape(json_encode($option))`.

Comment: Tried it. I get this error again.
If instead of adding any other number - the result will be the same

Comment: try this `$this->db->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "cart SET \`option\` =  '" . $this->db->escape(serialize($option)) . "'  WHERE cart_id = '" . (int)$cart_id . "' AND customer_id = '" . (int)$this->customer->getId() . "' AND session_id = '" . $this->db->escape($this->session->getId()) . "'");`

Comment: Thank you so much. Is there a result. !